# PHP Can't run MPI from shell-exec() function

Tags: c, openmpi

I have a web interface to controlate a cluster with OpenMPI, I use shell_exec() function to execute mpirun, when i try to execute with "-host local" it works perfectly but when i run with the command "-hostfile /home/hostfile" it does nothing.

If i put the command in the console it works perfectly but the same command in shell_exec() doesn't work.

Command that is not working from shell_exec:

> cd /mpi; mpirun -np 64 -hostfile /home/hostfile17 paralelo 1 image.bmp
>   out.bmp

But that command works perfectly from the console.

Any idea on what is going on?.

Comment: Are you sure that the hostfile is in `/home`? It is very untypical of a Unix system to have files stored in `/home` rather than in `/home/username/`.

Comment: Yes it is in "/home/hostfile17".

Comment: Check the access permissions of `/home/hostfile17` and make sure that it is readable by the web server. Also make sure that the web server's user can log into the nodes listed in the hostfile over SSH without password, e.g. with a passwordless key.

Comment: Hi @JohnSmith Did you succeed running mpirun from php? I'm facing the same problem. In my case the user is www-data but everything was build under another user name. Does it work with absolute paths? Should I add a new www-data user on every node?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

PHP's [shell_exec](http://www.php.net/shell_exec) function will execute your command under a non-login user. This just means that $PATH & other environment variables that you would expect would not be provided.
Just be explicit about where your `mpirun` is located, and use absolute paths to ensure MPI knows what your talking about.

*Example:*

```
/usr/local/bin/mpirun -np 64 -hostfile /home/hostfile17 /full/path/paralelo 1 /mpi/image.bmp /mpi/out.bmp
```